# MapView clustering with custom annotations

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm trying to cluster my mapView with custom annotations but cluster is never being called. This is my code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation{
        return nil
    }
    
    let an = MKAnnotationView.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "AD")
    an.clusteringIdentifier = (annotation as! StopAnnotation).id!.joined(separator: "_")
    an.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "face")
    return an
}
```

This never triggers clustering, I also implemented this delegate:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations memberAnnotations: [MKAnnotation]) -> MKClusterAnnotation {
    return MKClusterAnnotation(memberAnnotations: memberAnnotations)
}
```

Which is also never called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that `clusteringIdentifier` isn't unique for every cluster. Since you're passing `(annotation as! StopAnnotation).id!` I'm guessing it is uniq.

From Apple documentation :

> Clustering occurs when there is a collision between multiple annotation views **with the same identifier** on the map surface.

You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/2867297-clusteringidentifier).